# Error while pip installing EvalML on terminal

Tags: python, machine-learning, pip, pyproject.toml, pyproj

I am trying to install EvalML. I am getting an error, I am not able to understand what to do next.
the error is,

```
"Building wheels for collected packages: vowpalwabbitBuilding wheel for vowpalwabbit (setup.py) ... errorerror: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

```
× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.│ exit code: 1╰─> [50 lines of output]running bdist_wheelrunning buildrunning build_pycreating buildcreating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\vowpalwabbitcopying python\vowpalwabbit\dftovw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\vowpalwabbitcopying python\vowpalwabbit\pyvw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\vowpalwabbitcopying python\vowpalwabbit\sklearn.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\vowpalwabbitcopying python\vowpalwabbit\sklearn_vw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\vowpalwabbitcopying python\vowpalwabbit\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\vowpalwabbitcopying python\vowpalwabbit_init_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\vowpalwabbitcopying python\vowpalwabbit_main_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\vowpalwabbitrunning egg_infowriting python\vowpalwabbit.egg-info\PKG-INFOwriting dependency_links to python\vowpalwabbit.egg-info\dependency_links.txtwriting top-level names to python\vowpalwabbit.egg-info\top_level.txtreading manifest file 'python\vowpalwabbit.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'warning: no files found matching 'CMakeSettings.json'warning: no files found matching 'python*.bat'warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'explore'Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64
```

```
    could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin\\cmake.exe' failed with exit code 1
  [end of output]
```

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.ERROR: Failed building wheel for vowpalwabbitRunning setup.py clean for vowpalwabbitFailed to build vowpalwabbitERROR: Could not build wheels for vowpalwabbit, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects"
```

First I was trying to install evalml right in the jupyter book(where my project code will be). later I used terminal and tried using pip install there. from my understading, pyproject was not installed, I pip installed pyproject and it was installed successfully. also I installed pandas and numpy just be sure. After that, I tried again installing EvaML yet same error was there.

Answer (score 0):

I, personally, was not able to replicate this on VS Code. I would like you to check that you have the most recent version of PIP installed: `pip -V.` If you do, look around online for a possibly older version of this program and install it with `pip install vowpalwabbit==insert_version_here`. It could be that Eval wants to install and older version of it or something along those lines. Please remember to check other places before going on StackOverflow.

Comment: I am still getting an error like this, """Collecting vowpalwabbit==9.8.0
  Using cached vowpalwabbit-9.8.0.tar.gz (17.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: vowpalwabbit
  Building wheel for vowpalwabbit (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [50 lines of output]"""

Comment: Have you tried downloading a file from an unofficial Python binary or, more preferably, PyPi and using the pip command to install it?